# How can I change my Xbox LIVE Gold Family primary account?

Tags: xbox-network

The leader of your Xbox LIVE Gold Family pack is the "primary" account, who sets the rights/privileges for the other family user accounts. I want to make another account the primary, but am finding no obvious way to do this in the settings. Do I have to call a rep? Is this even possible, and how?

Answer (score 1):

The primary account cannot be transferred. You make to recreate the family membership with non-banned accounts, if that's the reason why you ned to switch.

Comment: What makes you think the accounts are banned?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can change the settings to have freedom but if you're trying to sign your account up instead of your primary then you're screwed.

Comment: "Freedom"? It's not clear what you're talking about here.

Comment: [Freedom](http://youtu.be/jR6mZO8PcSA?t=4m37s) is never clear...